# Multithreading issues when accessing shared List

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

The below pseudocode creates a "Boss" class which keeps track of and allows interfacing with "workers".

Each worker is a thread and is able to call back up to the calling class/thread by using a delegate to check properties of other workers.

1) Is the `CheckString` method thread safe and is there any issues using delegates between threads like this?

2) Does CheckString run under WorkerBoss thread of the workers thread?

```
class Worker
{
    private readonly Thread thread;
    public string CurrentString = "";

    public Worker(Action<string> CheckString)
    {
        thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Get random string
                CurrentString = GenerateRandomString();

                // Check random string against other workers
                if (CheckString(CurrentString))
                    Console.WriteLine("Other worker has this string!");
            }
        });
    }
}

class WorkerBoss
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public List<Worker> _workers = null;

    public WorkerBoss()
    {
        // Start 10 workers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            _workers.Add(new Worker(CheckString));
    }

    public bool CheckString(string textToCheck)
    {
        _locker.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // Iterate over workers and see if someone has this string
            foreach (var worker in _workers)
                if (worker.CurrentString == textToCheck)
                    return true;

        return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            _locker.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CheckString` runs under the thread that's calling it. Note that "WorkerBoss" does not have a thread.

Comment: Note that you have a race condition: the first worker can start executing `CheckString` (and therefore enumerate `_workers`) while the constructor of `WorkerBoss` is still executing and adding elements to that same collection.

Comment: Thank you @KevinGosse. In this situation I could just Start() those threads after they are initialized but for other cases would I use locking on that collection somehow?